# How to prevent user from sliding back mat-slider in angular material

Tags: javascript, html, angular-material

I am trying to use slider from material UI to indicate progress. User must be only allowed to slide forward. Is there any way to do that?
I could set the `min` value to current number but I am looking for something better.

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="progress">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Progress </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-slider thumbLabel [displayWith]="formatLabel" tickInterval="1" min="{{element.progress}}" step="25" max="100">
                    </mat-slider>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

This is what I tried. I want to make the slider value till `{{element.progress}}` fixed. User shouldn't be allowed to slide back

Comment: Post what did you try, without code we cannot help you!

Comment: Please check now. I have added the code